# Google oAuth not working after 3600 seconds

Tags: authentication, youtube, google-oauth

I'm using google oAuth for getting youtube latest streaming. It works for 3600 seconds. But then it stopped working. After some researching at stackoverflow, many people wrote to use "SetAccessType": "offline" .

I did it but same result.

Here is my snippet.

```
<?php

/**
 * Library Requirements
 *
 * 1. Install composer (https://getcomposer.org)
 * 2. On the command line, change to this directory (api-samples/php)
 * 3. Require the google/apiclient library
 *    $ composer require google/apiclient:~2.0
 */

$stream_id = "";

if (!file_exists(__DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php')) {
  throw new \Exception('please run "composer require google/apiclient:~2.0" in "' . __DIR__ .'"');
}

require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
session_start();


$OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID = '972289696318-q037nr25oti8gs5h7hcj5lfkl7erklh6.apps.googleusercontent.com';
$OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET = 'cbmQyfeXWGb93RkN7KSHLQKB';

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAccessType('online');
$client->setClientId($OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID);
//$client->setExpires_in('10000000');
$client->setClientSecret($OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET);
$client->setScopes('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube');
$redirect = filter_var('http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],
    FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
$client->setRedirectUri($redirect);




// Define an object that will be used to make all API requests.
$youtube = new Google_Service_YouTube($client);

//print_r($youtube);

// Check if an auth token exists for the required scopes
$tokenSessionKey = 'token-' . $client->prepareScopes();



if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
  if (strval($_SESSION['state']) !== strval($_GET['state'])) {
    die('The session state did not match.');
  }



  $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
  $_SESSION[$tokenSessionKey] = $client->getAccessToken();
  header('Location: ' . $redirect);
}

if (isset($_SESSION[$tokenSessionKey])) {
  $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION[$tokenSessionKey]);
}
/*
if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
    $refreshToken = $client->getRefreshToken();
    //print_r($refreshToken);
  //  $client->refreshToken($refreshToken);
    $newAccessToken = $client->getAccessToken();
    $newAccessToken['refresh_token'] = $refreshToken;
    file_put_contents($credentialsPath, json_encode($newAccessToken));

}
*/

// Check to ensure that the access token was successfully acquired.
if ($client->getAccessToken()) {


  try {
    // Execute an API request that lists broadcasts owned by the user who
    // authorized the request.
    //print_r($youtube);
    $broadcastsResponse = $youtube->liveBroadcasts->listLiveBroadcasts(
        'id,snippet',
        array(
            'mine' => 'true',
        ));

    //print_r($broadcastsResponse);

    $htmlBody .= "<h3>Live Broadcasts</h3><ul>";
    $count = 0;
    foreach ($broadcastsResponse['items'] as $broadcastItem) {
     // print_r($count+1);
      $count = $count+1;
      if($count == 1) {
      $htmlBody .= sprintf('<li>%s (%s)</li>', $broadcastItem['snippet']['title'],
          $broadcastItem['id']);

      $stream_id = $broadcastItem['id'];
      }
     // print_r($broadcastItem);
    }
    $htmlBody .= '</ul>';

  } catch (Google_Service_Exception $e) {
    $htmlBody = sprintf('<p>A service error occurred: <code>%s</code></p>',
        htmlspecialchars($e->getMessage()));
  } catch (Google_Exception $e) {
    $htmlBody = sprintf('<p>An client error occurred: <code>%s</code></p>',
        htmlspecialchars($e->getMessage()));
  }

  $_SESSION[$tokenSessionKey] = $client->getAccessToken();
} elseif ($OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID == 'Replace_me') {
  $htmlBody = <<<END
  <h3>Client Credentials Required</h3>
  <p>
    You need to set <code>\$OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID</code> and
    <code>\$OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID</code> before proceeding.
  <p>
END;
} else {
  // If the user hasn't authorized the app, initiate the OAuth flow
  $state = mt_rand();
  $client->setState($state);
  $_SESSION['state'] = $state;

  $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
  $htmlBody = <<<END
  <h3>Authorization Required</h3>
  <p>You need to <a href="$authUrl">authorize access</a> before proceeding.<p>
END;
}
?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>My Live Broadcasts</title>
</head>
<body>
  <?php echo $stream_id; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Any idea what can i do?

NB:  My purpose is, any one can authenticate here and can get latest youtube streaming id. But I'm struct with oAuth after 3600 seconds.

:(

Comment: here it seems like you are using only access token.You need refresh token also.

Answer (score 0):

Your Access Token has an expiry time. The expiry usually is half an hour (1800 seconds), although this can vary. The value is set by the Authentication Server. The expiry time is sent to you along with the Access Token.

After the Access Token expires, the server will no longer accept it. You must request a new one using your Refresh Token. You should  have gotten it along with the first Access Token.

If you do not have a Refresh Token, you'll have to log in again.